# What is nmap command to get the device type?

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to scan two targets which are the printer and router. Is there an option in Nmap to have it print device type as mentioned in the following link?
[Device Types](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-device-types.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: add `-O -v`. -O indicates OS detection, and -v indicates verbose output.  https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html